# How to select lines closest to another set of lines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro

[image: Two sets of line feature classes]

In the image shown above, I am trying to select lines marked in green color that are closest to the blue lines **along the direction of the blue lines**. I did a lot of Google searches, but I could not find the tool that will help me accomplish this task. How can I perform this selection?

Comment: You mean the desired green lines have to be parallel to the blue ones?

Comment: No, the desired green lines will intersect the blue lines if blue lines are stretched along its length. Also, if a green line already intersects a blue line, then it's treated as being the closest. Assume that only one green line can intersect with the blue line at any roadway location.

Comment: It sounds like you want to select the first line that is encountered when a single segment line is extended (in the same direction) for an infinite distance at either end.

Comment: @PolyGeo, yes! You got it right.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Advanced or Standard level license of ArcGIS Desktop then I think the tool which will be useful for you to investigate is [Extend Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm):

> This tool extends line segments to the first intersecting feature
>   within a specified distance. If no intersecting feature is within the
>   specified distance, the line segment will not be extended.

If you have only a Basic level license then I think you will need to work with geometry in ArcPy.

Comment: From the description, it seems like this tool will help me with the selection task. I will try using it and will ask for further help if it doesn't work the way I expect.